# Finding cells in a 3D grid with free neighbors

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I have a program, where the `get_free` function below has the most major computational cost by far, and I was wondering if there was a faster way to do it. Perhaps an all-`numpy` solution would be faster.

The task is to find the indices of the third dimension in a three-dimensional boolean array where the cell (as specified by the two first dimensions) and its neighbors (as given by the `neighbors2` function) are 0. That's what `get_free` does.

Don't worry too much about understanding the `neighbors2` function, it doesn't do much heavy lifting. The indices can be returned in two formats, as specified by the docstring, which can be helpful for some numpy-functions.

Any feedback, regarding code quality in general or for optimizing performance is appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

rows, cols = 7, 7
depth = 70
state = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(rows, cols, depth)).astype(bool)


def neighbors2(row, col, separate=False):
    """
    If 'separate' is True, return ([r1, r2, ...], [c1, c2, ...])
    if not, return [(r1, c1), (r2, c2), ...]

    Returns a list of indices of neighbors (in an hexogonal grid)
    within a radius of 2, not including self.
    """
    if separate:
        rs = []
        cs = []
    else:
        idxs = []

    r_low = max(0, row-2)
    r_hi = min(rows-1, row+2)
    c_low = max(0, col-2)
    c_hi = min(cols-1, col+2)
    if col % 2 == 0:
        cross1 = row-2
        cross2 = row+2
    else:
        cross1 = row+2
        cross2 = row-2
    for r in range(r_low, r_hi+1):
        for c in range(c_low, c_hi+1):
            if not ((r, c) == (row, col) or
                    (r, c) == (cross1, col-2) or
                    (r, c) == (cross1, col-1) or
                    (r, c) == (cross1, col+1) or
                    (r, c) == (cross1, col+2) or
                    (r, c) == (cross2, col-2) or
                    (r, c) == (cross2, col+2)):
                if separate:
                    rs.append(r)
                    cs.append(c)
                else:
                    idxs.append((r, c))
    if separate:
        return (rs, cs)
    else:
        return idxs


def get_free(cell):
    """
    Return the indices of a a cell that are 0 and
    where all its neighbors are 0 for the same depth
    """
    candidates = np.where(state[cell] == 0)[0]
    neighs = neighbors2(*cell, False)
    free = []
    # Exclude elements that have non-zero value in neighboring cells
    for candidate in candidates:
        non_zero = False
        for neigh in neighs:
            if state[neigh][candidate]:
                non_zero = True
                break
        if not non_zero:
            free.append(candidate)


print(timeit.timeit("get_free((4, 4))", number=100000,
      setup="from __main__ import get_free"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your `neighbors2` is a [*pure function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). I think you could speed things up by memoizing the results:

```
def neighbors2(row, col, separate=False):
    global _neighbors2_memoized

    args = (row, col, separate)

    if not _neighbors2_memoized:
        _neighbors2_memoized = { } # Start with empty dict
    elif row_col_sep in _neighbors2_memoized:
        return _neighbors2_memoized[args]

    # rest of your code

    if separate:
        result = (rs, cs)
    else:
        result = idxs

    _neighbors2_memoized[args] = result
    return result
```

Of course, a little searching will yield hundreds of `memoization decorators` and the like for python.

**Update**

Also, I think what you are doing is looking for "layers" or "levels" at which the given `cell` has all its neighbors empty.

If so, consider recoding your check to use `intersect1d()`. The neighbors are going to be constant - it's the same neighbors at each level.

So make a similar *candidates* array for each neighbor, and treat it like a set: "this is the set of levels where neighbor (ij) is zero".

Then, compute the intersection of that set with the `candidates` set (which is just the set of levels where `cell` is zero).

This is basically a large `and`: cell is zero AND neighbor(ij) is zero AND ...

You can execute `len(neighbors)` numpy operations instead of looping in python.

```
def get_free_setwise(cell):
    """
    Return the indices of a a cell that are 0 and
    where all its neighbors are 0 for the same depth
    """
    neighbors = neighbors2(*cell, False)

    candidates = np.where(state[cell] == 0)[0]

    for n in neighbors:
        candidates = np.intersect1d(candidates, np.where(state[n] == 0)[0])
        if len(candidates) == 0:
            break

    return candidates


print(timeit.timeit("get_free((4, 4))", number=10000,
      setup="from __main__ import get_free"))
print(timeit.timeit("get_free_setwise((4, 4))", number=10000,
      setup="from __main__ import get_free_setwise"))
```

Output of this was (note: number=10,000):

```
0.8349439720041119
6.3053770850092405
```

About seven times slower. However, when I raised `depth` to 700, the times were almost equal, and when I raised depth to 7000, the times were

```
3.6607714939891594
2.716483567011892
```

So the numpy-centric version does better as `depth` increases (FWIW).

**Update 2**

Using bitwise ops I was able to get better performance:

```
# Neighborhood pre-computation for get_free5. This is a one-time thing - the
# neighborhoods will never change as long as the rows,cols stay the same.
# NOTE however that these arrays are TRANSPOSED, because that's what free5
# does.

neighborhood = []
for r in range(rows):
    neighborhood.append([])
    for c in range(cols):
        hood = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=np.bool_)
        hood[r,c] = 1
        for nb in neighbors2(r, c):
            hood[nb] = 1
        hood = hood.T # Transpose!
        # Now hood is all 1's for neighbors. Do this same computation
        # in the same fashion that the state-updater does.
        bytestr = np.packbits(hood).tobytes() + b'\0'
        uint = np.frombuffer(bytestr, dtype=np.uint64)
        neighborhood[r].append(uint[0])

neighborhood = np.array(neighborhood, dtype=np.uint64)
# Neighborhood[r,c] is a bitmask with all neighbors + (r,c) set to 1
# NOTE: +(r,c) - the neighborhood explicitly includes the center point,
# which is not true for the neighbors function. I am using this to test for
# the center ALSO being zero at the same time - just one pass through the
# state array.

def get_free5(cell, *, verbose=False):
    """
    Return the indices of a a cell that are 0 and
    where all its neighbors are 0 for the same depth
    """
    result = list(np.nonzero(state_asbits & neighborhood[cell] == 0)[0])

    # This if statement is used in my self-test code. Delete all this code
    # for production use.
    if verbose:
        orig = get_free(cell)
        missing = [n for n in orig if n not in result]
        extra = [n for n in result if n not in orig]
        print("Missing from result, found in orig:")
        for n in missing:
            print("orig: (transposed)", n)
            print(etats[n])
            print("bits: {:64b}".format(state_asbits[n]))
            print("mask: {:64b}".format(neighborhood[cell]))

        print("Found in result, not found in orig:")
        for n in extra:
            print("orig: (transposed)", n)
            print(etats[n])
            print("bits: {:64b}".format(state_asbits[n]))
            print("mask: {:64b}".format(neighborhood[cell]))

    return result

# Setup for get_free5(). This code has to be run whenever the state[]
# array changes or is computed. It's an alternate encoding of the state array
# so if you don't need state[] for anything except this check, you can get
# rid of it. Otherwise, you'll have to call this before you start calling
# get_free5()

# Transpose, to get all the values at the same depth in a contiguous area.
etats = state.T
bitplane = []
for d in range(state.shape[-1]):
    #bytestr = np.packbits(etats[d]).tobytes()
    #if len(bytestr) % 8 != 0:
    #    bytestr += b'\00' * (8 - len(bytestr) % 8)

    # Hard-coding for 7x7 - append one extra byte
    bytestr = np.packbits(etats[d]).tobytes() + b'\0'
    uint = np.frombuffer(bytestr, dtype=np.uint64)
    bitplane.append(uint[0])

# state_asbits[n] is an array of 64-bit numbers, holding bits for each of the
# 49 cells at depth=n. If the value in state[r,c,n] is 1, then the bit at
# state_asbits[n].get_bit(r,c) == 1. These values can be trivially checked
# using bitwise AND operations, with the mask values in the neighbors array.
state_asbits = np.array(bitplane)
```

This code runs faster than the original version, but that doesn't include the computations I have to do for the state_asbits array. I think that's pretty cheap, but I don't know how often you are updating it.

```
$ python test.py
original code 8.314752619000501
free5: bitwise 1.1757051760068862
```

Comment: I'll implement memoizing this evening, I'm sure it'll help and it's a useful technique to remember. As for the set intersection, the depth parameter is domain determined and so will not increase beyond 70; I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Are the rows,cols also guaranteed to be <7?

Comment: (because 49 booleans will fit into an int64, which opens a whole bunch of solutions involving bitwise ops)

Comment: Sure, we can make that assumption, so long as converting to/from array-form is fast, such that the rest of the code does not have to deal with a change in data structure.

Comment: Including the encode, not including decode, it's about 4 times slower. There's just one change in the array, followed by `get_free`, followed by another change then `get_free` again and so on. So encode/decode is definitely not negligible, however I might consider changing all the other code considering how fast it is excluding encode.

Comment: Is the underlying data really a bunch of booleans? Or is that "encoding" really part of the `get_free` process?

Comment: Yes, it really is. Specifically, the data models a grid of cellular towers, like the ones cell phones connect to. Each xy/cell is a tower. The third dimension is the channels, where each channel is either in use by some caller or not. `get_free` finds the channels that are available for new callers, and to avoid interference you have to check that the neighboring towers don't have an ongoing call on these channels.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like changing the data representation is the way to go. My code deliberately (over-) uses numpy to manage the bits, but you should probably just create a set of bitmasks one per cell and try a direct 64-bit approach.

Comment: If the channels are bitmasks, 2 x 64 bits would store availability, and a set of bitwise OR or AND ops get you the result without having to call `np.where` first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66299/discussion-between-tsorn-and-austin-hastings).

Answer (score 1):

One improvement, with bitwise or:

```
 def get_free2(cell):
    """
    Return the indices of a a cell that are 0 and
    where all its neighbors are 0 for the same depth
    """
    neighs = neighbors2(*cell, False)
    f = np.bitwise_or(state[cell], state[neighs[0]])
    for n in neighs[1:]:
        f = np.bitwise_or(f, state[n])
    free = np.where(f == 0)[0]
    return free
```

The results, 200000 iterations:

```
get_free (original) 8.616401553998003
get_free2 (this post) 6.426983985002153
get_free5 (@Hastings, including encode) 37.249181182996836
```